# How to integrate backbonejs with presistencejs websql?

Tags: backbone.js, web

I'm wondering how to integrate backbone js (http://backbonejs.org/) with persistence js(https://github.com/zefhemel/persistencejs).

the problem is backbone models need to be updated to use the new lib models instead of the restful one.
I tried to use:

- backbone.nopersistence: but all data is saved in memory only,
- backbone.localStorage: but I need to save data in websql not just localStorage

Comment: I haven't used persistencejs before, but I would probably start by taking a look at [backbone.localstorage](https://github.com/jeromegn/Backbone.localStorage) to see what kind of updates he did to `Backbone.sync`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this adapter: https://github.com/MarrLiss/backbone-websql. It's not persistencejs, but it saves to websql at least.

**Edit**: you can find a better solution here: https://github.com/retrofuturistic/backbone-scaffold. It overrides the default Backbone.js sync API and provides DAO objects to access WebSQL through persistencejs.

Comment: Thx a lot but I'm wondering how to build relations(one to one ...) between objects using it.

Answer (score 0):

After more investigation I found that the best solution is to use persistence models instead of backbone models because backbone models are designed to use restful apis.